# Why binding to MinWidth doesn't work?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store

In my application I created templated control. Now I want to bind MinWidth to dependency property. For example in my xaml I have

```
<ColumnDefinition  Width="Auto" MinWidth="{TemplateBinding ColumnWidth}"/>
```

and in my code

```
public double ColumnWidth
{
    get { return (double)GetValue(ColumnWidthProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ColumnWidthProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty ColumnWidthProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        "ColumnWidth", typeof(double), typeof(Schedule), new PropertyMetadata(200));
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work and I dont know why. MinWidth is always 0. Maybe someone knows what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Look at your `Output' window. Are there any `Binding` errors reported there?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! There's no need to add tags to your title, there's a tag system for that. Please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190 for the general discussion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why the `TemplateBinding` won't work in your case, but you could always replace it by a regular `Binding` like this:

```
<ColumnDefinition MinWidth="{Binding ColumnWidth,
                             RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"/>
```

---

I've tested this in a ControlTemplate of a custom control. `TemplateBinding` doesn't work, `Binding` does.